# Conan cannot find a certain package for the specified settings, options and dependencies

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, cross-platform, conan

I am working on a small C executable project using Jetbrains CLion *2019.3*, MinGW *8.1*, and also the Conan C/C++ Package Manager *1.21.1*. I am refreshing my knowledge about C and want to learn about new tools like Conan. My main development environment is Windows, but this project is intended to be cross-platform; I would like to be able to build and run the application on Linux/Unix as well.

Since my application needs to compute signatures using `HMACSHA1`, I want to use the OpenSSL library, so I added the `OpenSSL/1.1.1a@conan/stable` package to the `requires` section of my `conanfile.txt` file, and I also created a Conan profile for `MinGW` that has the following options:

```
toolchain=$MINGW64_PATH
target_host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
cc_compiler=gcc
cxx_compiler=g++

[env]
CONAN_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$toolchain
CHOST=$target_host
AR=$target_host-ar
AS=$target_host-as
RANLIB=$target_host-ranlib
CC=$target_host-$cc_compiler
CXX=$target_host-$cxx_compiler
STRIP=$target_host-strip
RC=$target_host-windres

[settings]
os_build=Windows
arch_build=x86_64

# We are cross-building to Windows
os=Windows
arch=x86_64
compiler=gcc

# Adjust to the gcc version of your MinGW package
compiler.version=8.1
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
```

The `MINGW64_PATH` points to my MinGW installation folder.

When running `conan install` it complains about a missing package (obviously a dependency package of OpenSSL) that does not exist:

```
zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable: WARN: Can't find a 'zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable' package for the specified settings, options and dependencies:
- Settings: arch=x86_64, build_type=Release, compiler=gcc, compiler.version=8.1, os=Windows
- Options: minizip=False, shared=False
- Dependencies: 
- Package ID: eb34f13b437ddfd63abb1f884c4b8886c48b74cd

ERROR: Missing prebuilt package for 'zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable'
Try to build it from sources with "--build zlib"
Or read "http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package"
```

Since I am a noob using Conan, I have no clue how I can fix this problem. What needs to be done to fix this issue, and also can I fix this on my own, or do I need help from the package author?

I found a description of the `Missing prebuilt package` error at https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package, but it does not help much.

Comment: Installing perl fixed it for me, e.g. on Fedora `sudo dnf install perl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so I added the OpenSSL/1.1.1a@conan/stable package to the requires

That package is obsolete, you can check it on [Conan Community](https://github.com/conan-community/conan-openssl) repository. You should try `openssl/1.1.1a@` instead, which is maintained by the new [Conan Center Index](https://blog.conan.io/2019/09/04/A-new-binary-building-service-for-Conan-center-packages.html).

```
conan install openssl/1.1.1d@
```

Where is the namespace? It has been removed, take a look on [more information about recipes](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/wiki#more-information-about-recipes).

> Since I am a noob using Conan, I have no clue how I can fix this problem. What needs to be done to fix this issue, and also can I fix this on my own, or do I need help from the package author?

As the [FAQ](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package) recommends, you should build by yourself, running the command proposed by the error message:

```
conan install openssl/1.1.1a@ --build zlib
```

But I'm sure it won't be enough, you will need to build OpenSSL too. So, the best approach in your situation is:

```
conan install openssl/1.1.1a@ --build missing
```

Now, Conan will build from sources anything which is not pre-built on server side.

To summarize, this is not an error, like something is broken.

When you asked for OpenSSL 1.1.1a, Conan found the recipe on [Conan Center](https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center), which explain how to build OpenSSL, however it didn't find your pre-built package, following your settings and options.

Well, MingW is not used in Conan Center Index, because there is no enough demand, all [supported platforms and configurations](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/wiki/Supported-Platforms-And-Configurations) are listed in the Wiki. But this specific recipe should support MingW, since when it was part of Conan Community, MingW was present in package lists for building.

I would say, you can use 1.1.1d instead, which newer and safer than 1.1.1a.

Comment: I have added the conan-community remote according to this: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/remotes.html and also found the  1.1.1d-package at https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center/openssl%3A_/1.1.1d%3A_, but I am not able to install it. The conan client fails with the error `ERROR: Unable to find 'OpenSSL/1.1.1d' in remotes`. What am I missing?

Comment: Or you forgot to add `@`, or is because you are using CamelCase. As described, it's lowercase and uses `@` as suffix.

Comment: Good point regards the casing; I tried `conan install openssl/1.1.1d@ -r conan-community`, which fails with `ERROR: Requested 'openssl/1.1.1d' but found case incompatible 'OpenSSL'
Case insensitive filesystem can't manage this`. Is it because the deprecated package is still in the cache?

Comment: Okay; removing the `OpenSSL` package from the cache using `conan remove OpenSSL/*` and then installing it via `conan install openssl/1.1.1d@_/_` did the trick, while `conan install openssl/1.1.1d@` did not work.

Comment: Because openssl/1.1.1d@ is not part of Conan Community, when accessing the link https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center/openssl%3A_/1.1.1d%3A_ you will see a button named "Set me Up", which contains all steps needed to the the package. All packages that don't have a namespace (user/channel) are part of conan-center remote. As you read in the docs, conan-center is defined by default in your remote list. To summarize, run `conan install openssl/1.1.1d@ -r conan-center`

Comment: The related error "found case incompatible" is because you had both OpenSSL and openssl installed. Conan uses the package's name as key, and in that case you had different packages with same name, but different case. You did right, you need to remove the old one by passing `conan remove "OpenSSL/*"` and installing the new one.

Comment: Also, you if you need to search a package, you can use https://conan.io/center. It has the same behavior than running `conan search` but it's a web view, more friendly.